# How to solve this differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'(x)= f(x), \quad 0<x<1$$

Why is the answer  $$y(x)=c+\int_1^x f(s)\,ds\qquad?$$

I thought the integral would be from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Clearly $y(x)$ is a function **of $x$**, so there should be an $x$ somewhere.

Comment: I agree with you , why we integrate from 1 to x , what if I integrate from 0 to x. Thanks

Comment: It honestly comes out the same because $c$, our constant, takes care of all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $y'(x) = f(x)$ on $0<x<1$ we can integrate both sides from $1$ to $x$:

$$\int_1^x y'(s)ds = \int_1^x f(s)ds,$$

so,

$$y(x)-y(1) = \int_1^x f(s)ds,$$

and

$$y(x) = y(1) + \int_1^x f(s)ds.$$

Note that $y(0)$ is simply a constant so we can replace it by $c$ if you wish. In response to your comment, yes we can also integrate from $0$ to $x$ instead (in fact, that is what I naturally do!). This will simply change the constant $c$ in your equation.

Comment: There are many ways to represent the solution.  Intuitively, starting at $x=0$ starts with $y(0)$ and incrementally changes $y(\Delta x)$ by a small change $f(0) \Delta x$. Starting at $x=1$ starts with $y(1)$ and incrementally changes $y(1-\Delta x)$ by the small change $-f(1) \Delta x$. You are just choosing different ways of "building" the solution from some starting point!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!